# ¿Cómo puedo ver la IP de mi computadora?

Tags: windows, cmd, ip

Necesito saber la IP de mi computadora, cuyo sistema operativo es Windows.

Comment: Quieres saber la dirección IP del computador en la red local, o la dirección IP con que estás conectado de cara al mundo? Si es la primera, qué sistema operativo utilizas?

Comment: Esta no es una pregunta de programaciòn, por lo que pienso que debe ser eliminada.

Comment: No especificaste su sistema operativo, pero asumimos que es windows

Comment: Para la IP pública, ¡¡¿Intentaste escribir [`IP`](https://www.google.com/search?q=IP) en google?!!

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no trata sobre programación.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo teclea cmd en el buscador de windows y en la pantalla negra que te aparezca(la consola de windows) coloca el comando **ipconfig** y te aparecerá la información que necesitas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en esto, fue de mucha ayuda amigo Blidge.

Comment: De nada amigo, sigue aprendiendo.

Answer (score 2):

**IP PRIVADA DESDE EL  Símbolo del sistema**

1. La tecla **Windows**+ la letra **R**,
2. se te abre un ventaja de ejecutar y escribirás **CMD**,das enter
3. escribes **IPCONFIG** das enter y ya tienes tu **IP PRIVADA**

**IP PUBLICA DESDE EL  Símbolo del sistema**

1. La tecla **Windows**+ la letra **R**
2. se te abre un ventaja de ejecutar y escribirás **CMD**,das enter
3. Escribe la palabra **ftp**, y das enter.
4. luego escribe  **ftp.opera.com** y das enter.
5. te pide un usuario sera **anonymous**
6. te pide contraseña pero solo oprime enter
7. por ultimo escribiremos **literal stat**  das enter
   donde dice connected to **IP PUBLICA**

Comment: Habiendo **tantas** páginas de "cuál es mi ip", realmente crees que iniciar sesión en un FTP es lo mejor?

Comment: - como el subtitulo lo dice IP PUBLICA DESDE EL CDM

Comment: ¿CDM? ¿¿[Celebrity Death Match](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celebrity_Deathmatch)?? ... El título lo puede decir, pero me parece una mala recomendación.

Comment: Que otra manera conoces para a averiguas un IP publica desde el CMD

Comment: Como te mencioné, es mucho más sencillo utilizar uno de los servicios de las tantas páginas de "cuál es mi IP"... Por ejemplo, utilizando opendns, sólo hay que escribir esto en la consola `nslookup myip.opendns.com. resolver1.opendns.com`